# Jersey Client Single String in Body

Tags: java, c#, json, model-view-controller

I am calling a C# web service from my java jersey client which has the interface for the controller:

```
  ([FromBody] string Message)
```

What should the code look like for the java client.  It keeps giving me a null value for "Message"

This is my code I have so far:

```
    Invocation.Builder builder = webTarget.path("api/message/").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Response post = builder.post(Entity.json(message));
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue with my java code?  I basically need a string in the body and no json.

Comment: What is your json?

Comment: It's just a text and nothing else.

Comment: Well yes.. but *what* text?